# Angular performance in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was faced the performance issue of ng-repeat directive, I rendered the PDF formFields using ng-repeat directive, somehow it halts my browser. But when I use track by $index and limitTo:1 together in same ng-repeat, it works fine and it enhances the rendering speed. I can't understand the logic behind this but it works extraordinary fast :)

1. This works faster and fine for me, also limitTo:1 not work, some how it is binding the limit with $index and halting of browser issue fixed.

   ```
       <div ng-repeat="friend in friends track by $index | limitTo:1">
                 {{ friend.id }} &mdash; {{ friend.name }}
               </div>
   ```
2. if we use limitTo before track by $index than it behaves normally the limit behavior of angular js which is understandable

   ```
     <div ng-repeat="friend in friends | limitTo:1 track by $index">
                     {{ friend.id }} &mdash; {{ friend.name }}
                   </div>
   ```

OR

```
        <div ng-repeat="friend in friends | limitTo:1">
                      {{ friend.id }} &mdash; {{ friend.name }}
                    </div>
```

Although i achieve my performance goal, but i want to know the logic behind this.
Here is the link of jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/neglingeyes/G6q84/

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: he "can't understand the logic behind this" so maybe he wants an explanation for what is going on ..? maybe he wants to sell bricks, not sure -.-'

Comment: my question is, i cant understand the how limitTo and track by $index work together and how can it enhances the speed.

Comment: did you try to use brackets?

Comment: Exactly ! [.](http://example.com)

Comment: It is still not clear to me which one works, which one doesn't kai which one is faster. Also, create a fiddl to demonstrate your observation would be very interesting.

Comment: track by statement must ALWAYS be at the end, so your #1 is not valid.

Comment: @ExpertSystem
You just make your own demo, and will find the difference clearly.
I used first option in my enterprise application and solve my issue.
Here i put this question to clearing my concept and also help other who facing the performance issue in ng-repeat directive.

Comment: @aet 
My first statement is valid and try it out .. you will see the differences dear

Comment: My point is that in your case #1 you are not in fact tracking by $index you are tracking by id. ng-repeat caches the elements to be faster. ng-repeat also does row by row insertion for the purposes of animation, among other things. So tracking by id is faster for your application. Rather than limitTo:1 you could also try filtering with an ng-show on the repeated element. In my experiments this is always faster than using a filter inline in the repeat.

Comment: @Shani: In order to understand what was really going on in your application (which resulted in better performance **in your case**) we need to re-create other conditions which we do not have knowledge about (so you are the only one that can create demos).

Comment: @Shani: Just pretending that changing the order of operators has the sole effect of affecting performance is naive; we know there are other side-effects, so if we want to track them down, understand why in your case those side-effects did not affect the functionality and make a general pattern out of it (indicating in which case the above "technique" would work and in which it wouldn't) we need all the relevant info (which again only you can provide).

Comment: @aet: `ngRepeat` adds and removes nodes (i.e. does DOM manipulation) which is way slower than applying CSS styles to nodes (which is what `ngShow/ngHide` do. On the other hand, removing the elements from the DOM has the benefit that is destroys the watchers associated with them thus improving performance. Hiding an element using `ngShow/ngHide` leaves its watchers anaffected, so they keep getting evaluated at every digest loop.

Comment: True, @ExpertSystem, but it creates other problems, like when you are filtering and sorting, sometimes re-creating those dom elements is too expensive. In the end I resorted to using _ templates and precompiling elements and storing them in a $cacheFactory cache, but my custom ng-repeat is extremely fast :)

Comment: Ok, i'll make a jsfiddle for this tomorrow.

Comment: @aet: I didn't say one is preferred over the over. I just pointed out that each approach has its merits and its drawbacks and one should be aware of both in order to decide which approach works best for the situation at hand

Comment: @ExpertSystem
Here is the link of jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/neglingeyes/G6q84/

Comment: @Shani: Firt of all your fiddle is incorrect in many ways: 1. Cases A and B have identical `ngRepeat` expression. 2. You use global `startTime` variable which means that all 4 `ngRepeat`s modify the same variable making the calculated time useless. 3. Calculating the endTime using `timeout` (which fires at the next rendering) yields the endTime unreliable (aka useless). If you fix those issues, you will notice that the first two cases are virtually identical (and which ever comes first usually needs a couple more milliseconds). **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/G6q84/2/)**

Comment: @Shani: In any case, looking at the source, it turns out that indeed `f in fs track by i` and `f in fs track by i | limitTo:1` get parsed into the exact same value, so there is absolutely no difference. Let me know if you would be interested in more thorough exlanation.

Comment: @ExpertSystem, you will not see any difference in small data, if u use in large amount of data than you will see difference, and also u manually call post-repeat directive one by one. I'll call post-repeat in ng-repeat injsfiddle for sake of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can not measure multiple ng-repeat directives at once with post-repeat.
This is because the way it tries to figure out when the rendering is complete is to set a timeout function for the next event loop tick, and that really means all the directives on the page have finished rendering, not just this specific ng-repeat.
In your demo fiddle, I guess each next post-repeat timeout gets processed in a separate event loop tick or something like that, and this is why their "measured" performance seems to get worse and worse. If you changed their order, again the first will seem to be the fastest. But only by a couple of ms - a trivial difference.

Have you tried to benchmark each case separately? Also, on what platform and with what data? On desktop browsers and with such short data it is too fast to make a difference either way.

As to what the first code segment does - it is parsed as `friend in friends track by ($index | limitTo:1)` ("What brackets?" ;-) )
The `limitTo` filter can only be applied to arrays, not to scalar variables like the number `$index`. But the angular filters normally return their input unchanged if they can not make sense of it, so I guess that is what happens here too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation:

by default ng-repeat creates a dom node for each item and destroys that dom node when the item is removed; As it watches the ng-repeat object, it expects the object to change & implement the change & hence keep adding or deleting nodes. But using $index it reuses DOM nodes.

Here is the link where I picked up this information- http://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/2cvo16/speeding_up_angularjs_with_simple_optimizations/